# VB.NET Stream Writer UTF-8 not ANSI

Tags: vb.net, utf-8, stream, ansi

My code is basically this:

```
Dim writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter("C:\file.exe")
writer.Write(Chr(CInt("&H80")))
writer.Close()
```

I'm writing an executable so UTF-8 is not working well for me. When I write &H80 (80) it gives me
(E2 82 AC) which is the UTF-8 representation of '€'. I've tried everything, is there ANY way I can write in ANSI? What should I do?

Comment: "Binary" is what you're looking for.

Comment: What do you mean for 'writing an executable'. The code tries to  write a single byte in a file with an exe extension. This is hardly an executable. Could you explain what are your intentions here?

Comment: @Steve are you serious? Would you rather me have posted 2KB of hex data just to prove that it's an entire executable? What I posted is something called an EXAMPLE... Anyway I solved my problem thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing text and binary data: the data types `String` and `Char`, which is returned by `Chr`, are inherently linked to an encoding and are only to be used for text.

For working with binary data, use a `Byte` array.

Similarly, the `StreamWriter` class is for writing *text* to a fine, not binary data. To write binary data, use the [`BinaryWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) class.

Comment: Right, but the question is not very clear. How could the OP name  that file an executable is beyond me.